# how make query about some of a field are equal?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying the code below

```
SELECT Sum(Price) FROM Faktor WHERE date=date
```

but it shows total of all price. I want to show the sum of per day like:

```
date ----- sum
2015/5/1  12345
2015/5/2  54124
```

I have tried below code too but get error:

```
SELECT date,Sum(Price) FROM Faktor WHERE date=date
```

> [Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Column 'Faktor.date' is invalid in the
>   select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate
>   function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: What is the purpose of `WHERE date=date`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT [date],SUM([Price])
FROM Faktor
GROUP BY [date]
```

Not sure why you'd use date=date, so I left it out.

Answer (score 3):

Just as the error message tells you, you need to use a `group by` clause and  the *date* column needs to be in it.

```
SELECT date, SUM(Price) 
FROM Faktor 
WHERE date=date -- this looks a bit odd... maybe you want a range of dates or something?
GROUP BY date
```

With SQL Server all non-aggregated columns from the select statement needs to be grouped (unlike some versions of MySQL for instance).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    date
    ,SUM(Price)
FROM 
    Faktor
WHERE 
    --add date rules here if you have date criteria  i.e. date >= 'someDate'
GROUP BY
    date
```